# Exploiting own application

Tags: c, gdb, exploit

I am trying to learn how to do buffer overflows by following this tutorial: http://www.ouah.org/readmeneu.htm but I can't get the exploit working.

Sources, exploit.c: http://pastebin.com/b95G2KK7 and server.c: http://pastebin.com/PM4GdcT7 . The shellcode that is being used is http://pastebin.com/fuGgDeAH .

I modified the exploit.c and the server.c to get them running. 
Compiled server.c with -fno-stack-protector and set /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space to 0. Also I tested the shellcode (gcc shellcode.c -z execstack; ./a.out; netcat 127.0.0.1 64713) and it works.

From what I understand the exploit.c does the following:

1. Fill buffer with NOP
2. Put shellcode in the middle of the buffer
3. Fill the end of the buffer with the wanted RET (0xbfff620)
4. Send the buffer (incl. shellcode)
5. The RET of the program then should execute the shellcode

So I load gdb and run the server program.
When executing the exploit program it gives a segmentation error and returns the right RET address.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0xbffff620 in ?? ()

The output of (gdb) 'x/400bx $esp-200' can be seen at the url: http://pastebin.com/bCqphFNn it looks correct..

Unfortunately the program does not open a port on 127.0.0.1 64713.

(gdb) show stack shows me:

> eip = 0xbffff620; saved eip 0x90909090
>
> called by frame at 0xbffff62c
>
> Arglist at 0xbffff62c, args:
>
> Locals at 0xbffff62c, Previous frame's sp is 0xbffff628
>
> Saved registers:
>
> ebp at 0xbffff620, eip at 0xbffff624

I'm not sure how to continue now; how can I get the exploit working? What am I missing?

*** Updated ***

I've compiled the server.c using the (-g) and the (-z execstack) options. When working from gdb: the exploit does seem to work (it opens a port on 64713). But when I try to connect to that port using nc or telnet the server.c receives a SIGSEGV signal (on 0xbffff6fc); the port 64713 is still open but does not respond to any commands..

Without gdb: the server.c still receives a segmentation fault when ./exploit is executed.. no port is opened.

Comment: Did you try `-z execstack` when compiling `server.c` as well? Your shellcode is being placed on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it did do something: the program does not produce a SIGSEGV on the execution of the exploit.c but now SIGSEGVs when trying to connect to the remote shell.

Comment: Used both the original shell code (as on the website) which opens the port on 31337. When connecting to the port the program SIGSEGVS on 0xbffff690. When using the shell code which I included above (the pastebin) it does open a port on 64713 but also when I try to connect to it server.c SIGSEGVs on -xbffff6fc. The ports both stay open and are non-responsive..

Comment: Whats the address in `$esp`? I have a feeling you just copied the address to jump to from the website and its not the same in your program. Also please stop saying `it segfaults` you're running two programs im having trouble figuring out _what_ program is segfaulting. Server.c or exploit.c Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, exploit.c is running fine, server.c is the program that segfaults.. print $esp gives 0xbffff68c.

Comment: It seems that the shell code is now getting executed (because a port is opened) but when I connect to that port the server.c segfaults, the port is then still open but does not respond to any commands..

Comment: I've run into issues before where `$esp` is different in gdb than it is in the normal program as gdb loads some stuff onto the stack for debugging and whatnot. Let me confirm this and figure out how to get around it. Also, you normally want your shellcode and return addr at the end of the buffer. You want to fill the bottom of the buffer up with no-ops so you can `ret` to anywhere in the buffer and no-op slide into your shell code. lastly, compile with -g